# library_private_types_in_public_api and StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, dart, lint

After upgrade the linter to the new version (`flutter_lints: 2.0.1`) in my pubspec
the linter enables this rule:
[library_private_types_in_public_api](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#library_private_types_in_public_api) by default. I don't understand why. In my App project there are a lot of widget classes extended by `StatefulWidget`. The state class is always private. [Example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) projects do it the same way. Can someone explain why this rule make sense?

Btw.: I know i can disable this rule.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I encountered the same issue, it seems that now when you generate a `StatefulWidget` instead of returning say `_ExampleState` in the `createState` method it now returns `State<Example>` which avoids returning a private type. I ended up updating all of my widgets to this approach.

so

```dart
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

can be rewritten as

```dart
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  // you can also now use a super initializer for key 
  // if you are using dart 2.17
  const Example({super.key});

  // now returning State<Example>
  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: To use Dart 2.17 and higher, edit your `pubspec.yaml` and under `environment:` use this: `sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"`