# "Avoid using private types in public APIs" Warning in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been working on a flutter project and I have noticed ***Avoid using private types in public APIs***.
Is there a way to fix this warning?

```
 class SubCategoriesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final MainModel mainModel;

  // final Ads ad;

  const SubCategoriesPage(this.mainModel, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SubCategoriesPage createState() { // Avoid using private types in public APIs.
    return _SubCategoriesPage();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [library\_private\_types\_in\_public\_api and StatefulWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72233178/library-private-types-in-public-api-and-statefulwidget)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Because `createState` method return `State<Example>` so it's preventing returning any private `State`.

You need to update your code like this.

```
class SubCategoriesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final MainModel mainModel;

  // final Ads ad;

  const SubCategoriesPage(this.mainModel, {super.key});

  @override
  State<SubCategoriesPage> createState() { // Avoid using private types in public APIs.
    return _SubCategoriesPage();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem

```
class CotizacionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CotizacionScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<CotizacionScreen> createState() => _CotizacionScreenState();
}
```

I solved it by changing the:

```
@override
_CotizacionScreenState createState() => _CotizacionScreenState();
```

by:

```
@override
State<CotizacionScreen> createState() => _CotizacionScreenState();
```

Answer (score 5):

Since this is a `StatefulWidget`, I'm guessing the `_SubCategoriesPage` class inherits from `State`, since it's being returned by `createState()`.

If so, the return type can be changed to `State`. Since `State` is public, it can safely be returned from the public `createState()` method.

Comment: thank you very much for this answer. But can you please provide the changes that I need to make in this code ?

Answer (score 0):

this would be the solution:

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
const MyPage({super.key});

@override
State createState() => _MyPageState();
}

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I remove '_MyHomePageState'

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
   const MyHomePage({super. Key, required this. Title});

   final String title;

   @override  //Here remove _MyHomePageState
   createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

The code in _HomePageState class

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
   int _counter = 0;

   void _incrementCounter() {
     setState(() {
       _counter++;
     });
   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text(widget. Title),
   ),
   
   body: Center(
    child: Column(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: <Widget>[
         const Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
         Text(
           '$_counter',
           style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
         )
       ],
     ),
   ),

   floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
     onPressed: _incrementCounter, //click
     tooltip: 'Increment',
     child: const Icon(Icons.add),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better and simple solution.
Either, for all the files in your projet:
Modify in analysis_options.yaml at the root of your project

```
  rules:  
    library_private_types_in_public_api: false
```

Either, for a single file in your projet:
add the comment

```
// ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
```

above the line with problem (although they says it can be at the start of the file, it doesn't work for me.
Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

Just change `_SubCategoriesPage` by `State`

For those using Riverpod, change `_SubCategoriesPage` by `ConsumerState`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue using this code

```
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPage({super.key});

  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
  }
```

I tried using this method -  State createState() { // Avoid using private types in public APIs.
return _MyPageState();
but than I got this error message - The name MyPageState isn't a type so it can't be used a type argument.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So what was the answer to the above comments?